# Implementation of data structure for "phone directory"

Tags: java, collections

I have a phone directory with details like this:

```
ABc -> 123 
bcd -> 345 
cda -> 523 
abc -> 678
```

So if I want to see `ABc` person's phone numbers, I should get the both numbers. How can we implement this in java? means which **data structure** will be the best?

Comment: Please take more time when posting a question here and try to demonstrate some knowledge regarding the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: @MarounMaroun well pls advise for the solution i have tried in this way..Build a symbol table with KEY,VAL pairs. VAL can be a linked list of strings. When adding a new KEY,VAL pair into the symboil table, if the KEY is present, append VAL to already existing VAL. 
At query time, given string s, return VAL for given KEY=s it the KEY exist, return null otherwise.

Comment: That's a specification. Why don't you start coding it?

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking for some **data structure** to handle this kind of data, I will offer using a **HashMap of ArrayLists** like this:

```
HashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>> phoneNumber
```

Then you will be able to assign a dynamic array of numbers (like `[123, 678]` to each key (like `"abc"`)
For this example, the code would be something like:

```
HashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>> phoneNumber = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>>();
    String key = "abc";
    int value = 123;
    if (phoneNumber.containsKey(key)) {
        phoneNumber.get(key).add(value);
    } else {
        ArrayList<Integer> arrayList = new ArrayList<Integer>(1);
        arrayList.add(value);
        phoneNumber.put(key, arrayList);
    }
```

Also if the letter case is important in this example, consider using `String.toLowerCase()` function, which makes the second line of code above, like this:

```
String key = "abc".toLowerCase();
```